# Angular Js Default Radio Button Selection

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using the following piece of code for selecting the first option for radio button, but somehow it doesn't seem to work

```
<label class="radio inline">
    <input type="radio" ng-value="true" name="smsEnabled" ng-model="contactNumberArray.smsEnabled1" ng-checked="true">Yes
</label>
<label class="radio inline">
    <input type="radio" ng-value="false" name="smsEnabled" ng-model="contactNumberArray.smsEnabled1">No
</label>
```

Can someone suggest some work around for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Hi in your controller you have to  set default value for contactNumberArray 
please see here: http://jsbin.com/dafoj/1/edit

JS:

```
  $scope.contactNumberArray ={

    smsEnabled1 : true
  };
```

HTML:

```
 <label class="radio inline">
    <input type="radio" ng-value="true" name="smsEnabled" ng-model="contactNumberArray.smsEnabled1" ng-checked="true">Yes
</label>
<label class="radio inline">
    <input type="radio" ng-value="false" name="smsEnabled" ng-model="contactNumberArray.smsEnabled1">No
</label>
```

Comment: i found the solution and also instead of ng-value, value attribute has to be used!!

Comment: there is always more to one solution of any problems